# Is there a specialised term for words that are almost always mispronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

With few exceptions, I hear people pronounce **enmity** *emnity*, **Wednesday** *Wensday*, and **prerogative** perogative.

Is there a proper term for this phenomenon?

Comment: *Wednesday* = "Wensday" is usually not considered a mispronunciation. More generally, how do you determine if something is a "mispronunciation" or not if it is "always" pronounced the wrong way? Just by looking at how it's spelled? Then what about words like *hymn, debt,* or *island* where some letters are standardly "silent"?

Comment: I would say a mispronunciation in this context is to not follow the printed letters with the spoken sounds. I'd be interested to know how *Wensday* isn't a mispronunciation of *Wednesday*. **Wed-nes-day**.

Comment: But the pronunciation of *island* as "eye-land" does not follow the printed letters. So is it a mispronunciation? The OED online lists the following pronunciations for *Wednesday*: . /ˈwɛnzdeɪ/ , /ˈwɛnzdi/ , U.S. /ˈwɛnzˌdeɪ/ , /ˈwɛnzdi/. You'll notice none of them have a /d/ before the /z/.

Comment: That *how-to-pronounce* doesn't say how it got that way. I'd be interested to find that out. I mentioned this in another situation: a short drive from my home is a main road called *Wellesley Street*. Everyone here (NZ) calls it WELL es ley Street. But it's named for the first Duke Of Wellington, Arthur Wellesley, pronounced WELLES ley.No matter who I explain that to and how accepting they are of the information and how in agreement they are with it needing to have it's proper pronunciation restored, they simply cannot say it the right way because of the weight and momentum of tradition.

Comment: Sure, but you're confusing two things here: spelling and history. Historically, the word *lady* was at one point pronounced more like *HLAV-dee-yeh*. (The first part is related to the word *loaf, loaves*). But the "v" sound was lost, and it seems meaningless to say that it would be "correct" to pronounce it today. Historically, the word *island* never had an "s" sound: the "s" in the spelling was inserted because people thought it was related to the Latin word *insula.* It seems wrong to me to say that it would be "correct" to pronounce it today.

Comment: So, the presence of a certain sound in the historical source of word, doesn't mean the modern word must be pronounced with that sound. And the presence of a certain letter in the spelling of a modern word, doesn't mean that the word must be pronounced with the sound associated with that letter.

Comment: Why, though? I'm hoping to find out more about the why.

Comment: Why is the two-syllable pronunciation of "Wednesday" considered correct today? Because some sounds were lost over time in the standard pronunciation, but the associated letters were not lost in the standard spelling. Other sounds have been lost in both the standard pronunciation and the standard spelling, like the "n" in *Saturday* "Saturn's day." The other two pronunciations have different histories and require different explanations.

Comment: @Daniel: Is How-ston or Hue-ston the proper pronunciation for *Houston*? How about Bark-ly or Burk-ly for *Berkeley*? The proper pronunciation of Wellesley, Massachusetts is different than the proper pronunciation of Wellesley St. in NZ, and you are just going to have to live with that fact.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't know how it is for those other names you mention (their history), but this street is named for a person, one who has not disappeared from history, and whenever HE is talked about, his name is pronounced correctly. I think there's a good case for the name being pronounced as his name is.

Comment: Berkeley, CA was named after Bishop Berkeley, who pronounced his name *Bark-lee*. Are you going to tell the hundred thousand people who live there that they're pronouncing their town's name wrong? Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider, ***metathesis***

> (phonetics, prosody) The transposition of letters, syllables or sounds within a word, such as in ask as /æks/. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis)
>
> *nucular* is a commonly used metathetic form of the word *nuclear* [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucular)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that. I think that works for most of what I was meaning. There might be a separate term for dropping a sound (like *perogative* for *prerogative*). But this was a pretty useful answer.

Comment: @DanielStowers You're welcome, Dan!

Comment: Metathesis seems right to describe the pronunciation Daniel listed for *enmity,* but not for the ones listed for the other two words. For *Wednesday* and *prerogative*, the relevant change seems to be elision (in *prerogative*, there may also be a morphological reanalysis of the prefix).

Answer (score 1):

Just come across the word which describes the mumbling of Wednesday & prerogative.

> **Lenition**  ([Oxford Dictionaries /US English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/lenition))   The process or result of
>   weakened articulation of a consonant, causing the consonant to become
>   voiced, spirantized, or lost.

In UK English a more limited definition is given.

Answer (score 0):

Enmity and emnity are both correct pronunciations of two different words with different meanings. They are only mispronunciations if used in the wrong context (ie where the context implies the wrong meaning for the pronunciation used).

Enmity: a barrier ("...we should not create enmity between peoples")
Emnity: opposition to something ("there is emnity to the Taliban amongst many Afghans").

Comment: This would benefit from having the sources for your word definitions.

Comment: A search for 'emnity' produces no results in the Oxford English, Merriam-Webster, or Cambridge dictionary.